# Spring context is not loading after deploying on tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Am trying to load spring batch job context file on deployment of war.

I have added contextConfigLocation as below but not working.Even added spring-web in pom.xml but still when i deploy my war application onto tomcat spring is not being initialized.Please help me since i have referred to most of SO and spring forums answers,i dont want to use dispatcher servlet since this is not a web application as of now .It is just a batch job but in future it will be a batch job + web application ,at that time i will have a dispatcher servlet .Please let me know how to load spring on server start up.

My git repository where full code is present
    https://github.com/sumateja/patternfinder
    https://github.com/sumateja/patternfinder.git

tomcat logs

```
Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Development\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 3.12\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;.
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:patternfinder' did not find a matching property.
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 548 ms
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
    Dec 25, 2015 12:20:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 547 ms
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:equity-eod-job.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes finally this got solved . It seems that my web.xml was not being picked up ,since openshift had put the web.xml in webapps folder.Hence deleted this folder after copying WEB-INF folder to WebContent.When we download a project created in openshift into our workspace ,web.xml is present in webapps folder.Thanks prem for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your project on my machine. I did "mvn clean package". When I was about to copy the war file from target folder to tomcat webapps folder, I noticed that you are **packaging it as jar instead of war**. :)

change in your pom.xml, value of packaging from jar to war :

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>patternfinder</groupId>
    <artifactId>patternfinder</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>    <!-- This line from jar to war-->
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>patternfinder</name>
```

After this do:

1. mvn clean package
2. copy target/patternfinder-1.0.war to tomcat webapp folder
3. start tomcat

now you can see that your application will start loading. seems there is a wrong file path, in logs you can find FileNotFoundException occurring. I hope you can resolve this.

Comment: Thanks prem...but in my code in eclipse i had kept it as war packaging itself earlier and still it is was not working.I am using clean install and after that adding war to tomcat using Add/Remove option.